# Excel OfficeScript to extract date

Tags: excel, date, office-scripts

I need a script that will read a date from a cell and then generate the same date for future months.  For example, If cell A1 contains 01/13/2024, I want the code to generate 02/13/2024, 03/13/2024, 04/13/2024 ......  The issue that I am having is that I am unable to isolate the day of the month value (13) in this case.  I found code that can identify the value given today's date, but I am unable to have it read the date from a cell.  Below is the code that I have so far.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

let wsSh2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");

let myRange = wsSh2.getRange("A1");

var dt = new Date();

console.log(dt.getDate()));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`addMonth()` is utilized to generate a new date string. The second parameter, `shiftMth`, represents the number of months to shift.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let inputDateStr = selectSheet.getRange("A1").getText();
    let result = addMonth(inputDateStr, 2); // Shift two months
    console.log(result); 
}
function addMonth(inputDateStr: string, shiftMth: number) {
    // RegExp to extract date part, support: Dec. 16 2023 or 12/16/2023  or 2023-12-16
    let datePattern = /(\w{3}\.?\s\d{1,2}\s\d{4})|(\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4})|(\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2})/;
    let match = inputDateStr.match(datePattern);
    if (!match) {
        return "Invalid date!";
    }
    let inputDate = new Date();
    if (match[1]) {
        // Date format: Dec. 16 2023 
        inputDate = new Date(match[1]);
    } else if (match[2]) {
        // Date format: 12/16/2023 or 12-16-2023
        let [month, day, year] = match[2].split(/[\/-]/).map(x => Number(x));
        inputDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    } else if (match[3]) {
        // Date format:  2023/12/16 or 2023-12-16
        let [year, month, day] = match[3].split(/[\/-]/).map(x => Number(x));
        inputDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }
    // shift Month
    inputDate.setMonth(inputDate.getMonth() + shiftMth);
    // Get year, month, day
    let newYear = inputDate.getFullYear();
    let newMonth = inputDate.getMonth() + 1;
    let newDay = inputDate.getDate();
    // Format as "mm/dd/yyyy" 
    let formattedNewMonth = String(newMonth).padStart(2, '0');
    let formattedNewDay = String(newDay).padStart(2, '0');
    let newDateStr = `${formattedNewMonth}/${formattedNewDay}/${newYear}`;
    return newDateStr;
}
```

If you are confident that the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, the code can be simplified. The result of `dt.toLocaleDateString()` may be in the desired format, which is contingent on the OS's locale setting.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let wsSh2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
    let aDate = wsSh2.getRange("A1").getText();
    let [iMth, iDay, iYear] = aDate.split("/").map(x => parseInt(x));
    let dt = new Date(iYear, iMth, iDay);
    console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString());
    // If locale date format is different
    let newYear = dt.getFullYear();
    let formattedMonth = String(dt.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let formattedDay = String(dt.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let newDateStr = `${formattedMonth}/${formattedDay}/${newYear}`;
    console.log(newDateStr)
}
```